# String variable empty after assigning value from editText.getText().toString()

Tags: android, dialog, android-textinputedittext

I created a popup menu from a navigation drawer and everything works in regards to the actual popup. However, I have an EditText in the popup and would like the user to enter text into it and then click a button to do other things. My issue is that when I assign the EditText.getText().toString() value to a string variable in the function the string variable is still empty, and when I check for if EditText.getText().toString() is empty, it is not empty. So I don't understand how the assignment to a string variable still returns an empty string in the variable. I'm really new to Android programming so any advice would be appreciated. Thank you.

Snippet of onCreate method

```
public class workouts extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggle;
    private static final String TAG = "Workouts";
    private ExpandableListView listView;
    private ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
    private List<String> listHeader;
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> listHashMap;


    // Pop up menu variables
    private EditText categoryTitle;
    private Dialog myDialog;
    private String headerTitle = "";
    private boolean validTitle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_workouts);

        DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer);
        mToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.open,R.string.close);
        mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mToggle);
        mToggle.syncState();
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        final NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.navigationView);

        listView = (ExpandableListView)findViewById(R.id.expandable_list_view);
        initializeData();
        listAdapter = new expandableListAdapter(this, listHeader, listHashMap);
        listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        // Pop-up menu
        myDialog = new Dialog(this);

        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId())
                {
                    case R.id.back:
                    {
                        finish();
                        break;
                    }
                    case R.id.addCategory:
                    {
                        //View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
                        //listView.addHeaderView(header);
                        /*
                            1) Create pop-up menu w/ EditText box
                            2) Type in header group to add
                            3) Click create button
                            4) Add new header to list
                         */
                        try {
                            ShowPopup(item);
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Add pop-up: " + e.toString());
                        }
                        break;
                    }
```

Function to create popup
The string that i'm trying to fix is headerTitle

```
public void ShowPopup(MenuItem menuItem)
    {
        TextView textClose;
        Button btnAddCategory;
        myDialog.setContentView(R.layout.add_category_popup);
        textClose = (TextView)myDialog.findViewById(R.id.textClose);
        btnAddCategory = (Button)myDialog.findViewById(R.id.addCategory);
        categoryTitle = (EditText)myDialog.findViewById(R.id.category_title);
        headerTitle = categoryTitle.getText().toString();    // Header title to be used as hash key
        Log.i(TAG, "ShowPopup: Assigned header title");
        Log.i(TAG, "ShowPopup: " + headerTitle);
        textClose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                myDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        btnAddCategory.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(categoryTitle.getText().toString().isEmpty())
                {
                    categoryTitle.setError("Field cannot be empty");
                    categoryTitle.requestFocus();
                    validTitle = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    categoryTitle.setError(null);
                    validTitle = true;
                }
                if(validTitle) {
                    listHeader.add(headerTitle);    // Add header title to list of headers
                    List<String> newHeader = new ArrayList<>(); // Create new expandable list w/ 0 items
                    listHashMap.put(listHeader.get(listHeader.size() - 1), newHeader);
                    myDialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
        myDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        myDialog.show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should assign the value to the variable first:

```
        btnAddCategory.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                headerTitle = categoryTitle.getText().toString()
                if(headerTitle.isEmpty())
                {
                    categoryTitle.setError("Field cannot be empty");
                    categoryTitle.requestFocus();
                    validTitle = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    categoryTitle.setError(null);
                    validTitle = true;
                }
                if(validTitle) {
                    listHeader.add(headerTitle);    // Add header title to list of headers
                    List<String> newHeader = new ArrayList<>(); // Create new expandable list w/ 0 items
                    listHashMap.put(listHeader.get(listHeader.size() - 1), newHeader);
                    myDialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm not sure why i had to do the assignment inside the setOnClickListener, but it worked.

Comment: If you assign the variable in onCreate is will always be empty, because the user hasn't typed anything yet